# synchronize on method parameter

Tags: java

I have a pretty basic method,

```
//do stuff
}
```

. I was having issues in that new quotes would update the order, so I wanted to synchronize on the order parameter. So my code would like:

```
handleOrder(IOrder order) {
       synchronized(order){
        //do stuff
       }
}
```

Now however, intellij is complaining that:

```
Synchronization on method parameter 'order'
 Inspection info: Reports synchronization on a local variable or parameter. It is very difficult to guarantee correctness when such synchronization is used. It may be possible to improve code like this by controlling access through e.g. a synchronized wrapper class, or by synchronizing on a field.
```

Is this something I actually need to be concerned about?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because this type of synchronization is generally an indication that the code cannot easily be reviewed to ensure that deadlocks don't take place.

When you synchronize on a field, you're combining the synchronization code with the instance being used in a way that permits you to have most, if not all of the competing methods in the same file.  This makes it easier to review the file for deadlocks and errors in the synchronization approach.  The same idea applies when using a synchronized wrapper class.

When you synchronize on a passed instance (local field) then you need to review all of the code of the entire application for other synchronization efforts on the same instance to get the same level of security that a mistake was not made.  In addition, this will have to be done frequently, as there is little assurance that after the next commit, a developer will have done the same code scan to make sure that their synchronization didn't impact code that lived in some remote directory (or  even in a remote JAR file that doesn't have source code on their machine).

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but code design aside, will the synchronization actually fail? Meaning will one thread be able to reference this object, while the other is working on it? I'm not trying to remove value at all from what your saying, I'm just trying to exactly pinpoint the issue

Comment: @EthanSolomon `synchronized(order)` doesn't prevent other threads from manipulating `order`, it means that one thread per time can enter that block of code, which is what the answer addresses. The `order` is only used as a lock for the code block, it can be manipulated freely.

Comment: OTOH if all of the methods of `order` are synchronized, then the code `synchronized(order)` *does* prevent other threads from manipulating `order` freely.  But those are the sorts of things that a designer has to take into consideration.

Comment: Interesting. I had assumed that it would also prevent another thread from manipulating that order as well, which is what synchronized on a variable would usually do. Is that bc its method parameter?

Comment: @markspace unfortunately that wouldnt solve it. The goal is that the order object cannot be manipulated while this method is proccessing the order. I want it to be untouchable for 10 lines of code, not just the setters

Comment: Misread your comment, OK can you explain why that doesn't solve the issue?  The goal is to prevent order from being manipulated, why wouldn't synchronizing all methods work?

Comment: B/c if I want let's say the methods of the order object to be called in following order:
either: Thread1: (methodA-methodB)-Thread2:(methodC-methodD) or Thread2: (methodC-methodD)-Thread1:(methodA-methodB), this wont work unless I synchronize both the call of a and b, or c and d in each thread respectively with a synchronize on the object. Without that, even if the methods are synchronized, they could still be called a c b d

Comment: @EthanSolomon it doesn't "usually do that". Calling `synchronized(order) { Thread.sleep(FOREVER); }` in **any** context doesn't prevent other threds from manipulating `order`, unless those manipulations also involve acquiring that lock (e.g. calling a synchronized method of that same `order`).

Comment: If `order` has methods `methodA` `methodB` `methodC` `methodD` and those methods are all syncrhonized, and Thread1 executes `synchronized(order)` then Thread1 *definitely can* guarantee that it will execute both methodA and methodB in that order and no other methods will be called.  Same with Thread2 and Thread3.

Comment: If I say synchronized(order) { order.setA(), order.setB() } and then do synchronized(order) { order.setC(), order.setD() }, it will always run either a-b then c-d, or c-d then a-b, no? My question is that even though it is a method parameter, will that still be effective, regardless of bad design. Just pure java question

Comment: @markspace even if the order it is synchronizing on is a method parameter?

Comment: You cannot guarantee what order Thread1 and Thread2 will do their work.  That is the whole point of threads: asynchronicity and parallelism.  If you don't want that, don't use separate threads.  Just execute all four method calls on one thread.

Comment: why not? Is that bc its a method parameter? The whole point of synchronize is that you can take an object, and acquire the lock and make sure another thread can't get it. And obviously I would do what you suggested if it was a reality

Comment: @EthanSolomon The first attempt by a thread to syncronize on the object won't fail, but it may block.  Blocking is when the method isn't allowed to enter the synchronized region because a lock is held on the object by something else.  How would you know what that something else is?  You would normally look at the class that holds a member object, and inspect all the methods that synchronize on the member object.  But wait, you didn't specify a member object!  Now you have to look at all the source code for everything loaded into the JVM.  That's why you don't typically synchronize this way.